# All possible ways to declare Javascript variables

Tags: javascript

To create an IDE that would autocomplete all variables the user declares but would be oblivious to other variables such as `Math.PI` or even the module `Math`, the IDE would need to be able to identify all identifiers relating to variables declared by the user.  What mechanism could be used to capture all such variables, assuming you already have access to the AST (Abstract Symbol Table) for the program?

I am using reflect.js (https://github.com/zaach/reflect.js) to generate the AST.

Comment: Are trying to put some order in this horrendous language, sir?...

Comment: global declaration through `z = "fred"`

Comment: one line: `var lastname="Doe", age=30, job="carpenter";`

Comment: @DavidJashi Sadly, I am not doing anything so grand.  I would tell you the master plan, but it is proprietary.

Comment: In the third one only `m` is declared.  `a`, `b`, and `c` are not variables.  They are properties of the object.

Comment: is this specifically in a browser environment or does it include Node?/windows 8, etc.

Comment: or just undefined = `var unDef;`

Comment: By "declare a variable", do you mean add a variable to the current local scope where there previously wasn't one?

Comment: `var j = k = 1; // j and k are declared.` Nope. only `j` is declared here.

Comment: I consider many of the ways described to be the same, like the `for` one.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas You sure? http://jsfiddle.net/wGrdm/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: `k` is declared, it's just global.

Comment: @Ian Yes I'm sure. http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/wGrdm/1/ (check the console)

Comment: @BlackVegetable What is your goal? Your misuse of the termilogy makes the question difficult to understand. In JavaScript, there are only a few ways to *declare* a variable; what you've shown are not just declarations.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I see no `"use strict"` in the code above. You should mention that it only happens then instead of declaring it for all situations

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Why is it implied?

Comment: @RobW Forgive me, I have edited my answer; I believe I am trying to find out when an identifier is newly added to a symbol table.  It is tricky for me to know how to phrase this.

Comment: If you're writing your own parser/compiler, you may want to look at [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Comment: @BlackVegetable If you can't describe what you want, can you give an analogy? After reading your explanation, I imagine a text editor which auto-completes JavaScript code (with aid of the symbol table).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I'm not saying it shouldn't be used, I agree it should be, but I don't see why it's **implied**. Either the OP should mention that's what they're targeting or that's what you meant. Either way, good point

Comment: See the last paragraph of the edited question. He apparently wants to know anything that involves adding identifiers to the symbol table, not specifically variables.

Comment: @BlackVegetable You've got 9 answers already, none of them are useful. Can you edit your question to state the minimal requirements for an acceptable answer? Otherwise new single-line answers will keep popping up...

Comment: @BlackVegetable Hint for defining usefulness: Say what you're going to do with the answer. For example, "I will create one big Regular expression which uses all of these patterns" (I hope that you're *not* doing that though, it's unreliable).

Comment: @RobW I have edited the answer; hopefully the question can be salvaged.  Sorry for the mess.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `var j = k = 1;` is a misleading and dangerous anti-pattern. You make it sound as if it's fine because it fall-backs to a global variable.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I feel someone should note assignment in a j = k = N type pattern is not horrible, only declaration.

Comment: @BlackVegetable What AST do you have? [This one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API)? Please delete the old "obsolete" question from your question, and shape your question into something concrete. That would salvage your question.

Comment: Also, with the *new* question most of these answers are obsolete. @Mods? Course of action? flag one? flag many? downvote and let authors deal with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### I think it's pretty much impossible

Here is why I think it's pretty much impossible without executing it:

Let us go through the unexplored parts, from easy to hard.

#### Easy to catch:

**Function scope** is missed here:

```
(function(x){
    //x is now an object with an a property equal to 3
    // for the scope of that IIFE.
    x;
})({a:3});
```

Here is some fun dirty tricks for you all.:

Introducing... drum roll... **Block Scoping!!**

```
with({x:3}){
    x;//x is now declared in the scope of that with and is equal to 3.
}


try{ throw 5}catch(x){ 
    x // x is now declared in the scope of the try block and is equal to 5;
}
```

(people reading: I beg you to please not use these last two for actual scoping in code :))

#### Not easy:

Bracket notation:

```
var n = "lo";
a["h"+"e"+"l"+n] = "world"; // need to understand that a.hello is a property.
                        // not a part of the ast!
```

#### The really hard parts:

Let us not forget invoking the compiler **These would not show up in the AST:**

```
eval("var x=5"); // declares x as 5, just a string literal and a function call
new Function("window.x = 5")();// or global in node
```

In node.js this can also be done with the `vm` module. In the browser using document.write or script tag injection.

What else? Of course they can obfuscate all they want:

```
new Function(["w","i","n","dow.x"," = ","5"].join(""))(); // Good luck finding this!
new Function('new Function(["w","i","n","dow.x"," = ","5"].join(""))()')();// Getting dizzy already?
```

---

### So what can be done?

- Execute the code, once, in a closed, timed environment when you update the symbol table (just the relevant parts)
- See what's the generated symbol table is from the execution
- Boom, you got yourself a symbol table.

This is not reliable but it's probably as close as you get.

The only other alternative I can think of, which is what *most* IDEs are doing is to simply ignore anything that is not:

```
object.property = ... //property definition
var a = ... //scoped
b = ... //global, or error in strict mode
function fn(){ //function declaration
object["property"] //property with a _fixed_ literal in bracket notation.
```

And also, function parameters.

I have seen **no** IDE that has been able to deal with *anything* but these. Since they're the most common by far, I think it's perfectly reasonable to count those.

Comment: After the edited question, what he want *is* possible. An AST provides more than enough information. The trick is to extract the desired information from the huge amount of data. Real-world applications which show that such information can be extracted: JSHint, UglifyJS, Google Closure compiled - all of them keep track of variable assignments.

Comment: Oh my... The horror of this answer is of legendary proportions.  I will never view Javascript the same.

Comment: @RobW None of these (JSHint, UglifyJS, Closure Compiler) will find dynamic definitions, if I base64 decrypt a string into eval none of them will catch it (nor would it be reasonable to expect them to do so). IDEs and linters are _very good_ and I enjoy them, but some things are just not reasonable for them to find. If you see how I concluded my answer I think it sums it up nicely: "I have seen no IDE that has been able to deal with anything but these. Since they're the most common by far, I think it's perfectly reasonable to count those."

Answer (score -2):

By adding them onto am object that already exists....ie

window.mynewvar = 5;

```
function mynewfunc() {

}
```

Comment: That's not "technically" declaring a variable.  It's setting a property.  `window` just happens to be special.  If you had `var x = {}` and you did `x.mynewvar = 5`, that would *not* declare a variable.

Comment: @Rocket: Aren't _all_ Javascript variables just properties afterall?

Comment: @Rake36: I wouldn't say that.  What if you have `function abc(){ var x = 12; }`?  In this case, `x` is not a property of anything.

Comment: Yes, if you think about it all js variables are simply properties on the global/local object they are declared in.

Comment: @Braden: There's no such thing as a "local object".

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're right. There is only the function scope that the variables can be defined in.  You are still "declaring" a variable when you add a new property to an object, otherwise doing something like var a = 5 at the global scope would not be considered a declaration.

Comment: @Braden: I guess, but I wouldn't call `x.mynewvar = 5` a "variable declaration".  I'd call it a "property assignment".

Comment: @Rocket: I have to agree with you and admit the distinction between property and locally scoped (private) variable.  I naively assumed a local _var_ was accessible via some sort of property accessor, but I cannot find such a method.